# ROC curve memory error in generator function

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, generator, roc

I want to plot ROC curve.I have `preictprediction` as predictions and labels are generator.Then I use this line to convert generator to a list `y_true=list(generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, filesPath))` but I got this error in `generate_arrays_for_predict` the generator function.

`File "E:\test2\cnn_thesis2_test2.py", line 221, in generate_arrays_for_predict x=np.array([x]) MemoryError: Unable to allocate 32.3 MiB for an array with shape (1, 10, 22, 5, 3844) and data type float64`

I don't know how to solve this error.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
def generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
            x=np.array([x])
            x=x.swapaxes(0,1)
            yield(x)
preictPrediction=model.predict_generator(generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, filesPath), max_queue_size=4, steps=len(filesPath))
y_true=list(generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, filesPath))
fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(y_true, preictPrediction)
```

Comment: You try to create an `np.ndarray` of shape `(1, 10, 22, 5, 3844)`. That means storing 4,228,400 floating point numbers with 8 bytes each. That means ~32 MB. And apparently you don't have that much RAM left, so you get a MemoryError. I guess every element of your generator needs 32 MB and by creating the list, you save many arrays of that size. If you can process these arrays and do not need all numbers, process them one by one.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch How can I process them one by one ??

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. Does your `roc_curve` function really need a list of many five-dimensional arrays? If yes, then you simply do not have enough RAM for the things you want to do (or should kill other programs to free memory).

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I just want to plot ROC curve. I use `generate_arrays_for_predict` for spectrograms data, where each spectrogram (5,3844)  and each 10 spectrograms are saved in numpy file and each spectrogram have 22 channels sor each array `(1,10,22,5,3844)` due to having large data size i used generator function but I don't know how to plot ROC curve.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Do you know how to solve this error ??

Comment: The MemoryError can be solved by enabling Python to use more RAM (buy more or kill, other processes) or by not constructing an explicit list. I do not know your `roc_curve` function. so how am I supposed to know how to fix your problems?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch How by not constructing an explicit list?? IS there another way to construct list ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218647/discussion-between-niklas-mertsch-and-gigi).